# How to convert object column with date, time and NaN to datetime64 column in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, object, nan

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

date type

- COL1 - object
- COL2 - object

  | COL1 | COL2 |
  | --- | --- |
  | abc | 2019-11-12T20:15:08+030 |
  | ddd | 2019-12-01T22:14:11+030 |
  | bbb | NaN |
  | ... | .... |

How can I convert COL2 so as to have only date here (format: datetime64)? Be aware that I have many more columns in my original DF and COL2 could have NaN, so as a result I need to have something like below:

```
COL1 | COL2
-----|-------------------------
abc  | 2019-11-12
ddd  | 2019-12-01
bbb  | NaN
...  | ....
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: Does `pd.to_datetime` not work?

Comment: Skipped over the fact that you only need the date... maybe `pd.to_datetime(df["COL2"]).dt.date`?

Comment: Chrysophylaxs, it convert to object not datetime :/

Comment: In that case, `pd.to_datetime(df["COL2"]).dt.floor("D")`?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"COL1": ['abc', 'ddd', 'bbb'],
                   "COL2": ['2019-11-12T20:15:08+030',
                            '2019-12-01T22:14:11+030',
                            np.nan]})

df['COL2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COL2'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

indx = 0
df['COL3'] = ''
for element in df['COL2']:
    if not pd.isnull(element):
        df['COL3'].iloc[indx] = '{:04}-{:02}-{:02}'.format(element.year,
                                                           element.month,
                                                           element.day)
    else:
        df['COL3'].iloc[indx] = np.nan
    indx += 1

df['COL2'] = df['COL3']
df.drop(columns='COL3', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output is following:

```
  COL1        COL2
0  abc  2019-11-12
1  ddd  2019-12-01
2  bbb         NaN
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).